# android bluetooth :The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type BluetoothDevice

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

The method `getSystemService(String)` is undefined for the type `BluetoothDevice`

THE CLASS `TelephonyInfo` that accesses my sim cards on my phone is working

I want to use it to show the sim details on a device I'm connected to, I made some changes to include bluetooth, but I'm having a problem with the `methodgetSystemService`
The method `getSystemService(String)` is undefined for the type `BluetoothDevice` , 
I found some similar questions but none were using bluetooth, I tried their solutions but it didn't work since I'm using bluetooth. Here's the code after I've made some changes

I'm using this class to show the Sim details of a bluetooth device I'm connected to, I have the class `TelephonyInfo`

```
public final class TelephonyInfo {

    private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
    private String imeiSIM1;
    private String imeiSIM2;
    private boolean isSIM1Ready;
    private boolean isSIM2Ready;

    public String getImeiSIM1() {
        return imeiSIM1;
    }

       /*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
         TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
          }*/

    public String getImeiSIM2() {
        return imeiSIM2;
    }

     /*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
        return isSIM1Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
     TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
      }*/

    public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
        return isSIM2Ready;
    }

     /*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isDualSIM() {
        return imeiSIM2 != null;
    }

    private TelephonyInfo() {
    }

    public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice){

        if(telephonyInfo == null) {

            telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager)
                    bluetoothDevice.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                        "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                        "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                            "getDeviceId", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                            "getDeviceId", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you    
                    wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() ==
                    TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                        "getSimStateGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                        "getSimStateGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                            "getSimState", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(bluetoothDevice,
                            "getSimState", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you 
                    wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return telephonyInfo;
    }

    private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice,
                                            String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws
            GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        String imei = null;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                bluetoothDevice.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName,
                    parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                imei = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return imei;
    }

    private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice,
                                              String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws
            GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        boolean isReady = false;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                bluetoothDevice.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName,
                    parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
                if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                    isReady = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return isReady;
    }


    private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

        public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
            super(info);
        }
    }


}
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: try with this.getSystemService(String)

Comment: that's where the problem is Sathish Kumar J , the function getSystemService(String) is undefined for bluetoothDevice ,i was wondering if there is a similar function but compatible with bluetooth Device

Comment: and if i use this instead of bluetoothDevice ,it won't be applied on bluetooth device but anyway i get this error Cannot use this in a static context ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

> **getSystemService()** is a method of the class **Context**, so you'll need to run it on a context.

The original code you copied it from was probably meant to be run from an **Activity**-derived class. You need to pass a **Context** argument into your method if it's not inside an Activity.

Comment: Yes ,i think so , i'm sorry i'm a bit new at this ,i want the code to be usable with a bluetooth device (meaning get the sim details on a device i'm connected to via bluetooth ) i tried making some changes to the original code : here's the first code http://fr.androids.help/q15785 , please help ,what changes can i make ? thank you